# Options on the E-mini S&P 500 Futures at the CME: what's the expiry date of the underlying future?

Tags: united-states, options, futures

The  [Chicago Mercantile Exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_Mercantile_Exchange) (CME) has a variety of options on the E-mini S&P 500 (E1A,E2A,E3A,E4A,E5A,E1C,E2C,E3C,E4C,E5C,EW, EW1,EW2,EW3,EW4, and ES).

Looking at the contract specifications (e.g., [EW](http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/equity-index/us-index/e-mini-sandp500_contractSpecs_options.html?optionExpiration=U7#optionProductId=136) 
 ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170810150304/http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/equity-index/us-index/e-mini-sandp500_contractSpecs_options.html?optionExpiration=U7#optionProductId=136))), the underlying is the E-mini S&P 500 Futures.

[image]

However, there exists more than one current listed contracts for the the E-mini S&P 500 Futures. Specifically, as mentioned on  [E-mini S&P 500 Futures Contract Specs](http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/equity-index/us-index/e-mini-sandp500_contract_specifications.html?optionExpiration=U7&optionProductId=136) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170810150308/http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/equity-index/us-index/e-mini-sandp500_contract_specifications.html?optionExpiration=U7&optionProductId=136)), there are 5 listed for the the E-mini S&P 500 Futures (Five months in the March Quarterly Cycle (Mar, Jun, Sep, Dec)):

[image]

On which one are options on the E-mini S&P 500 Futures?

For example, if today (August 10, 2017) I purchase one call for EWQ7, does this mean that at 4:00 p.m. ET on the last business day of this month I have the right (let's ignore that [contrarian instructions are forbidden](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/83667/5656) for weekly & end-of-month options) to purchase the corresponding ESU6? or is it ESZ6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see EWQ6 in any of your links, so I can't say for certain, but when you buy an option contract on a future, the option will be for a specific future (and strike).  So the page you're looking at may be for options on E-mini S&P 500 futures *in general*, and when you actually purchase one through your broker, you pick a specific expiry (which will be based on the "prompt" future, meaning the next future that expires after the option) and strike.

UPDATE:

Based on [this page](http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/equity-index/equity-index-options-expiration-calendar.html) [mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170811050816/http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/equity-index/equity-index-options-expiration-calendar.html), the option EWQ7 is an option on the ESU7 (SEP 2017) future.  The next 3 monthly options use ESZ7 as the underlier, which confirms that they use the next prompt future as the underlier.

Comment: Thanks! EWQ6 = EW expiring on August 2016. (I should have written EWQ7)